# How do I communicate between devices in real-time using an internet connection?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, real-time, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I need my iOS app to communicate with it's clients similar to the way that a multiplayer game functions, where multiple devices are updated in real-time via an internet connection.

The iOS Multipeer Connectivity Framework will not work as it only supports local connectivity and is limited in the amount of devices that can be simultaneously connected.

So far, I've built a workaround using Parse to communicate between devices by constantly calling the database to check for changes in the object file and update the file locally on the device.  I know, a total hack that results in 60 api requests every minute. Is there another way to check for changes to the file on Parse and updating the file in local data storage?

Or, any alternatives for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You could send a push notification to appropriate clients when a relevant change has occurred.

Comment: Consider using Firebase.com? It will push the changes on connected clients instead of need to pull.

Comment: Have a look at Pusher or Realtime. This chat example might get you started: https://github.com/realtime-framework/MessagingObjectivecChat